# Django and Jenkins multiple errors on execute shell

Tags: django, shell, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to implement continuous integration for a python-django app. I installed Jenkins on a vps and created a job which pulls my bitbucket code.

Now I am trying to execute the tests from the tests dir, but something is failing within my execute shell in Jenkins.

Here is the shell console output:

```
    7 - Link the cms_core app in the project using a symbolic link

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ed1cms/test_cms_core
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  5 16:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  5 16:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins   16 Jul  5 16:12 cms_core -> ../core/cms_core
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins  811 Jul  5 16:12 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  5 16:12 test_cms_core
/tmp/jenkins7283490794872735254.sh: line 28: prinf: command not found
Collecting cms_core
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cms_core (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cms_core


8 - Finally, we can run the tests through django-jenkins

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs/tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs/tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs/tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs/tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs/tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs/tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cms_core'


9 - Deactivate virtualenv so it is destroyed

Removing temporary environment: tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c
Removing tmp-8ca50c09c788e0c...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

the 7,8,9 are steps I have written in the shell with printf so I could follow whats going on step by step. Until step 7 there are no errors taking place.

Here is my execute shell script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

printf "\n\n1 - Set-up some things so we can use virtualenvwrapper\n\n"
source ~/.bash_profile

printf "\n\n2 - Create a temporary virtual environment for Python\n\n"
mktmpenv -p /opt/python-versions/3.6.3/bin/python3

printf "\n\n3 - We need to go back to the path we initially were, not in the virtual env path\n\n"
cd -

printf "\n\n4 - Install requirements to be able to create a Django project and run tests\n\n"
pip install -r cms_core/tests/requirements.txt

printf "\n\n5 - Create the Django project\n\n"
rm -rf test_cms_core
django-admin startproject test_cms_core

printf "\n\n6 - Go in the project folder\n\n"
cd test_cms_core

printf "\n\n7 - Link the cms_core app in the project using a symbolic link\n\n"
ln -s ../core/cms_core .

pwd
ls -la

printf "\n\n8 - Finally, we can run the tests through django-jenkins\n\n"
./manage.py jenkins --settings=cms_core.tests.settings

printf "\n\n9 - Deactivate virtualenv so it is destroyed\n\n"
deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that you have a typo somewhere in your code. Just search for 'prinf', maybe a **t** is missing.
2. Your module cms_core is not installed or can not be found. Maybe you are just in the wrong folder to use your settings for django? Or check your virtualenv with pip list if all requirements are installed correct.

Comment: Double checked my shell script, cannot find a prinf mistake. Did a pip list in the shell and the list that pops meets all requirements. Hummm

Comment: I added a 'ls' before that line in the shell and in the current dir there are 2 dirs and 1 file:
cms_core
test_cms_core
manage.py

Comment: 1) Have a look at your jenkins config...maybe you enter there a bash call...the stack trace told us that you have anywhere a 'prinf'. At least have a look at this file >> /tmp/jenkins7283490794872735254.sh: line 28: prinf: command not found

Comment: 2) Try a workaround for your symlink and copy your files or use a direct path, maybe django doesn't get your link.

Comment: got rid of the prinf thing. Situation still the same tho. I dont know any workaround for the symlink at the moment. thanks for taking your time helping out